# REACT: Disable the first handler in nouislider at react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, disable, nouislider

In my React project I am using noUislider as a custom range.I need to disable first handler so that I can only move second.

In documentation I found the function: "slider.noUiSlider.disable(1)". When I use it I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: slider.noUiSlider.disable is not a function". Slider is defined, but hasnt this function as a method

Part of code where I need to disable handler

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import s from "./Bar.module.scss";
import Nouislider from "nouislider-react";
import "nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css";


const VideoBar = ({ duration, playingSeconds, setTime}) => {
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(null);

  useMemo(() => {
      if (slider) {
          slider.noUiSlider.set([null, playingSeconds]);
      }
  }, [playingSeconds]);
  useEffect(() => {
      if (slider) {
          slider.noUiSlider.disable(1);
      }
  }, [slider]);
  return (
      <div className={s.bar}>
          <span className={s.loaded} ></span>
          <Nouislider
              instanceRef={(instance) => {
                  if (instance && !slider) {
                      setSlider(instance);
                  }
              }}
              onChange={(e) => setTime(Math.round(e[1]))}
              id={s.playedId}
              range={{ min: 0, max: duration }}
              start={[0, 0]}
              connect
          />
      </div>
  );
};

export default VideoBar;
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a reproducible solution with code on code sandbox or Codepen. At least post the minimum code for debugging.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/xename123/react-1/main?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A29%2C37&workspaceId=7704a83c-120c-466c-b2cb-a7c57db05074. This is component that i get error. Not pay attention to the playingSeconds, you can change it if you need it

Comment: It's not accessible publically

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/xename123/react-1/main?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A11%2C36-11%2C50&workspaceId=7704a83c-120c-466c-b2cb-a7c57db05074 try it

Comment: Can't acess try this in incognito window to see if it's public first

Comment: I dont know why this is private. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/error-y4gx4f - this url from incognito window

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code in the question itself, using the formatting possibilities we provide.